# how to avoid bottom overflowed while animation - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

i have an AnimatedContainer and that container has an open/close animation when i tap on the container but there is a bottom overflowed by 38 pixels error.

shown in this video:

https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPsio8RS5BD0D1OzMbMA6sNCBamLF8nYEyml_-pPqKVe-tzza-PyvB3MQehdHKeNQ/photo/AF1QipPYOoZ6pOXARbd3SdpxY8OWegQxvFHtv2QNh7NQ?key=V0lhQnpPOWtCRm1RZ21yUnp6TkFZdmtKdWFuVk13

this is my code:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget> [
    GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
      duration: duration,
      child: all the content
    ),
    onTap: () {
      is_opened = !is_opened;  
    }
)
AniamtedOpacity(
  duration: duration,
  opacity: is_opened ? 1 : 0
      child: Container(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              //Icons and texts
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

thanks for the help

Comment: use expanded on your widget that consists of the animated container and the container

Comment: thanks you so much OMi Shah now it works!

Comment: you can also upvote my answer. Thanks.

Comment: how can i upvote your answer?

Comment: there's a upside arrow button just above the flag icon if you see before each comments

Comment: its not there: [image](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOnHNC26cAmDEawtviu_liCWebD9azSGVyentDNDC1XS9l9TDrKU8emJYl30oFuwg/photo/AF1QipMbOdXDaZBg_v-5yhk928hlZ4IKMH4eXe4YcYRI?key=TGhqWFBlNmhZQ3g2UWpQNW9Mbk9TQ05MeEYwN1VB)

Comment: I have just commented  my answer. Check below this reply. You will see a correct tick button just beofre the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap your `AnimatedContainer` widget with the [expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget so that it can expand and take required space when tapped.

Comment: @xxx check this. You will see the upvote button and correct tick button.

Comment: it says that i have less than 15 reputations because i dont use this account very much - i am so sorry! When i have 15 reputations i will come back and give you an upvote

Comment: I gave u one ☝️!

Comment: But this does not work on text widget

Comment: @PRATHIV can you post your issue in a separate post and i'll check out?